# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken SecurityException

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was getting this failure on a ICS device with latest Google Play Services when trying to call GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(args). The issue was resolved by removing and adding Google account to the phone. I wasn't able to reproduce the error. Google searching stack trace provided no insights. Any ideas on how this issue could be prevented and what it means are appreciated!

```
W/System.err( 3145): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices/prefix from pid=3145, uid=10055 requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
W/System.err( 3145):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
W/System.err( 3145):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.a$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.xxxxx.Backend.obtainSheetKeyAndInitService(Backend.java:112)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.xxxxx.Backend.fetchColumns(Backend.java:103)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.xxxxx.ProgressActivity$DummySectionFragment$3.doInBackground(ProgressActivity.java:288)
W/System.err( 3145):    at com.xxxxx.ProgressActivity$DummySectionFragment$3.doInBackground(ProgressActivity.java:1)
W/System.err( 3145):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
W/System.err( 3145):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err( 3145):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err( 3145):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
W/System.err( 3145):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W/System.err( 3145):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W/System.err( 3145):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

EDIT

As of time of reporting the bug:

- google_play_services-lib android:versionName="3.2.65 (834000-30)"
- Google Play Services version on device 4.0.31

Updated library to 4.0.30 and added requested permission to Manifest which seems to have worked. Waiting for Google to confirm that new library version fixes this issue because adding a new permission is a highly undesirable fix.

Bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61934

Comment: Are you requesting the `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES` permission, as the error suggests?

Comment: No, and documentation for Google Play Services doesn't say I should. Moreover I can't seem to reproduce this error - it works without requesting that permission most of the time. I guess I could throw in that permission into Manifest and hope that it would prevent the issue from occurring. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the version of Google Play Services that you were using when the error occurred? It looks like this may be a bug in the most recent release.

Comment: Epic Swords started getting this exact same error from our installed app users on 11/3, then on 11/5 it began to happen in LARGE numbers. Nothing changed in our code or permissions. Was something changed in GPS or the backend it communicates with?

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices/prefix requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, com.lootworks.swords.db.SwSqlTableProducts grantUriPermission()
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.a$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken

Comment: I don't know what zavidovych is using but our google-play-services-lib manifest says android:versionName="3.1.36 (673201-10)"

Comment: My app's install base started getting this same error this morning at 7:30am PST.  No changes to our code or permissions were made.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same error in one of our apps and it started happening during the 6th of November

Comment: It is happening to our app too. Got 1200 crashes today. More and more users have been affected. We are preparing a patch now with following changes: 1. add the READ_GSERVICES permission 2. use the latest Google Play Service Api. Hope Google can fix it before we release.

Comment: @Simon have you been able to confirm that READ_GSERVICES fixes it? That permission is weird, the only the reference I have seen is maps-specific https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start and even then it looks hacked-in, not like the other official ones. (I have not been able to repro this bug on a test device so still have only *LOTS* of error reports from customers)

Comment: I also received this crash today

Comment: I also got this error, ran an app on the emulator and aborted in the middle of a Google account sign-in flow. After that, any request go GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() fails with the error mentioned in the post. Adding the permission solves the problem though. Odd.

Comment: @mwk, I made an official build and one of my team members test it for one hour on four phones. Looks fine. I need QA to test it for a day to confirm it.

Comment: Having this issue too... There is Android bug reported for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61934 It seems this error was introduced with Google Play Service 4.0. I've added the permission com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES to my app and will see if it helped during next days...

Comment: Is this fixed? I was able to reproduce it yesterday, but not anymore

Comment: @Maragues we have never been able to repro this on a dev device (one reasons the bug is concerning) but we are still getting roughly the same rate of errors from installed users worldwide. However if the bug is due a bad update to GPS then even if Google releases a fix it will take a while to distribute and the errors fade out. What kind of device did you use to get it to reproduce?

Comment: @mwk We released a patch. The new build does not have such exception any more. My phone also automatically installed the update for me with the READ_GSERVICES permission.

Comment: @SimonXinCheng by "the new build" are you referring to your build or Google's build? I tried once from my N4 and it crashed. Because I couldn't fix it, I didn't test further. We are deploying a new version this week, so I need to know if this permission is necessary or not. I have not received more crashes, but we have a very small number of downloads and this bug only happens when creating an account/login in, so I don't know if it's fixed or no one else sent a report.

Comment: @Maragues We released a new build with the READ_GSERVICES permission a week before. No crashes any more. Google Play does not ask users to grant this permission when update. So auto update is working.

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Thats all.

Comment: this does fix the issue, but it's terrible that we have to do a fast deploy asking for a new permission, which always keeps users from upgrading

Comment: I'd like to hear from Google about what is causing this problem, and whether Google can remove this permission dependency for getToken() without requiring apps to add this permission. As @Maragues says there is no way we can force all users to upgrade. This is a very serious OS regression

Comment: We do not want to add any unnecessary permission. READ_GSERVICES is not well documented. Someone mentioned it is the worst permission to ask.

Comment: If you use Google Maps in your app, you have to include this permission. I don't see any harm in that. You are using Google's services and you should get permission to use them. Upgrading just for this permission is sad though.

Comment: @tasomaniac Not every application uses Google Maps. For example I only use GooglePlayServices to ask for permission to access the user's drive files and some info about the user. The main issue is that the permission is not well documented and it's not even mentioned in the play services documentation that it's required for `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`

Comment: We're also like to hear something official from Google before adding the permission. Eventually I guess we'll either add the mystery permission or remove GPS. But it would be good if Google could confirm the issue and what they can do to prevent similar problems in the future. We can't just have our installed base of users suddenly break like this, the only thing that saved us is we had wrapped all GPS calls in a full try/catch. But our next release requires auth so we need to pick a solution.

Comment: @tasomaniac I get this error on compiled google play apk! How should I add that line to manifest?!

Answer (score 2):

Today 2013-11-14 there has been a large drop in the number of error reports we have received due to this exception. Also I see Google Play Services version 4.0.33 is out, I didn't notice exactly when that released but it looks like yesterday.

Perhaps Google released a fix in 4.0.33? That would be great!

If anyone has been able to reproduce this bug, please let us know if 4.0.33 fixes it for you. (We have never been able to reproduce the bug on a dev device, although we have have zillions of traces from our installed base.)

[UPDATE] Google has definitely pushed a fix, we had only a handful of reports on 11/15 and zero on 11/16

Comment: The play store indeed says that the Services were updated yesterday (14.11) - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms