# binding to google play service close my app

Tags: android, google-play

I'm creating a app to purchase in app items. Every thing is fine. But on some phones, they can't open google play, every time trying to open google play, the home of google play just show up and close immediately. In my app, when I try to bind to google play, my app close immediately too. But my process wasn't be killed, Just the screen back to home screen. Is there any flag or some thing to set to avoid this?

My log for google play close is as follows:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices/prefix from pid=12038, uid=10082 requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, or grantUriPermission()
E/DatabaseUtils( 7206):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:332)
E/DatabaseUtils( 7206):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:188)
E/DatabaseUtils( 7206):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
E/DatabaseUtils( 7206):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
E/DatabaseUtils( 7206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm(12038): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41067360)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices/prefix from pid=12038, uid=10082 requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, or grantUriPermission()
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4211)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices/prefix from pid=12038, uid=10082 requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, or grantUriPermission()
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:411)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.google.android.gsf.Gservices.getStringsByPrefix(Gservices.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.google.android.gsf.Gservices.bulkCacheByPrefix(Gservices.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.google.android.finsky.config.GservicesValue$GservicesReaderImpl.<init>(GservicesValue.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.google.android.finsky.config.GservicesValue.init(GservicesValue.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.onCreate(FinskyApp.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4208)
E/AndroidRuntime(12038):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken SecurityException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816798/googleauthutil-gettoken-securityexception)

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace provides the answer: you need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't really understand why this would happen. It's  google play who crashed, but why my app would return back to home screen even my process wasn't killed. What I did is just bind to google play, and the play crash when reading database. I think it's the play need the permission. Is it because when the service crash it will close the activity bound to it also?

Comment: I get this error on compiled google play apk! How should I add that line to manifest?!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced by Google. Not sure there is a good workaround.
See thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/sePctoDJbRg%5B101-125-false%5D